# Not able to redirect using router in nextJs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

I am new to nextjs and was learning about routing, I have created following component in that is supposed to redirect to another page once we get a response from another API

```html
"use client"

import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Router from 'next/router';
//import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const theme = createTheme();

export default function TestComponent() {
  //const router = useRouter();
  const [postRes, setPostRes] = useState({});

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const postData = {
        firstName: 'firstName',
        lastName: 'lastName',
        userName: 'userName',
        email: 'email',
        password: 'password',

    }
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('/apis/auth/createUser',postData);
          if (response.data) {
            console.log("here");
            setPostRes(response.data)
          }
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error?.response?.data);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (postRes) {
        Router.push('/login'); 
    }
}, [postRes]);

  return (
    <Button onClick={()=> {handleSubmit()}}>
        click
        </Button>
  );
}
```

in above code I am getting the following error at line 46
Error: No router instance found.
You should only use "next/router" on the client side of your app.

even though I am using 'use client' in my component why is this still considered to be server side component? would be great if anyone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are on NextJS 13 - you are probably using the `app` router. You need to import `useRouter` from `next/navigation`
If this is the case you will need to do the following changes in their respective places:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
const router = useRouter();
router.push("/login");
```

Otherwise if you are using the `pages` router you will only need to do this:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const router = useRouter();
router.push("/login");
```